# Is it possible to send an object to a Chunk instead of an array

Tags: arrays, object, modx, modx-revolution, chunks

In Modx normally i build an array:

```
$props['example']['no_1'] = "example no. 1";
```

and then call the Chunk with

```
return $modx->getChunk('chunkname', $props);
```

In the Chunk i call this with:

```
[[+example.no_1]]
```

Is it possible to send an Object to the Chunk and show it? For example just like or something like this?

```
[[+example>getNo1()]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do it in this way:

```
return $modx->getChunk('chunkname', (array) $props);
```

if you want to use objects.

Hint: some modx objects have

```
toArray()
```

method.